# Como cambiar el contenido de un contenedor utilizando un wrapper

Tags: html, php7

He hecho una pequeña pagina en php y html, he incluido un navbar y un wrapper. Mi idea es la siguiente, me gustaría que al presionar un un boton del navbar o wrapper se cambiara el contenido del contenedor. He probado a hacer div, cada botón tiene su href y lo he utilizado de id en los div pero me salen uno debajo de otro y yo quiero que solo salga uno y al presionar se quite uno y se ponga el otro. Os dejo el código para que veas mas o menos como esta la cosa.

```
<!-- Sidebar -->
<div class="bg-light border-right" id="sidebar-wrapper">
  <div class="sidebar-heading">Panel de usuario </div>
  <div class="list-group list-group-flush">
    <a href="#Shop" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action bg-light">Tienda</a>
    <a href="#Profile" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action bg-light">Perfil</a>
    <a href="#Contact" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action bg-light">Contacta</a>
  </div>
</div>
  
<!-- /#sidebar-wrapper -->

<!-- Page Content -->
<div id="page-content-wrapper">
    

  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light border-bottom">
    <button class="btn btn-primary" id="menu-toggle">Menu</button>

    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>

    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
      <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto mt-2 mt-lg-0">
        <li class="nav-item active">
          <a class="nav-link" href="../index.html">Inicio <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">       
          <a class="nav-link" href="logout.php">Cerrar Sesion</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
      
  </nav>
<div>
    <div id="Shop">
          <img src="../img/carlos1.png" alt="">

    </div>
    <div id="Contact">

          <img src="../img/carlos2.png" alt="">
    </div>       
</div>
</div>
  
<!-- /#page-content-wrapper -->
```

Lo que me gustaría es que se mostrara una imagen al presionar en shop y la otra al presionar en contacta

Comment: Que has intentado?

Comment: Nada, porque no se como se podria obtener

Comment: Mira si quieres cambiar el contenido de un `div` de manera dinámica y  funcional, debes de usar `innerHTML` en Javascript. En tu casa en especifico yo recomendaría contener esos `href` en botones y añadirles un evento que invoque una función con `innerHTML` en Javascript. Por lo general, se plantean preguntas cuando ya se hizo una investigación previa. Te invito a investigar estos conceptos u otros que se adapten mejor a una solución a tu problema. Te dejo [esto](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), y te recomiendo leerlo. Saludos